# Show that if $a \le c$ and $b \le c$ then $a + b \le 2c$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \ge 0$. If $$a \le c,\quad b \le c,$$ then is $$a + b \le 2c\ ?$$

Is one allowed to add inequalities like that?

Comment: yes, if a < b and c < d then a + c < b + d

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this works! We can see why it works via the following argument.

Any inequality remains true if we add the same number to both sides. For example, if we know that $a\leq c$ than we also know that $a+1\leq c+1$ and $a+2\leq c+2$, and so on. In general, therefore, we can say that for any $b$ it follows from this first inequality that

$$a+b\leq c+b.$$

Now let's apply the same trick to this second inequality, $b\leq c$, i.e. add $c$ to both sides. Then we see that

$$b+c\leq c+c = 2c.$$

Finally, if one number is smaller than another number, and that number is in turn smaller than a third number, than the first number must of course also be smaller than the third number. In our case we have

$$a+b\leq b+c \qquad \text{and}\qquad b+c\leq 2c,$$

and therefore we may conclude that

$$a+b\leq 2c.$$